# No matching Localization found for Url

Tags: publishing, dd4t, broker

We are getting below error while deployment. Site goes down for 1-2 minutes and then automatically comes up. It usually happens when we do the deployment. Once we recycle app pool everything starts working fine. We are using DD4T 2.1.4 for `DD4T.model`, So 2.1 for DD4T and Web 8 for Tridion.

Nothing in Tridion API client logs and Discovery service logs, it seems like for 2-3 minutes we are losing connection to the Discovery service. please see below Exception:

```
2017-08-10 10:09:13.9939|ERROR|Global.Exception.Handling|System.Exception: No matching Localization found for URL 'http://www.xxx.xx/xxxx/' ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.DynamicMappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(String url)
   at SCA.Modules.Core.Resolvers.PublicationResolver.Resolve(Uri uri) in E:\LocalAgent5\work\eba82aa7dfd1d8ff\src\SCA.Modules.Core\Resolver\PublicationResolver.cs:line 103
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SCA.Modules.Core.Resolvers.PublicationResolver.Resolve(Uri uri) in E:\LocalAgent5\work\eba82aa7dfd1d8ff\src\SCA.Modules.Core\Resolver\PublicationResolver.cs:line 122
   at SCA.Modules.Core.Resolvers.PublicationResolver.FindMapping() in E:\LocalAgent5\work\eba82aa7dfd1d8ff\src\SCA.Modules.Core\Resolver\PublicationResolver.cs:line 77
   at SCA.Modules.Core.Resolvers.PublicationResolver.GetBaseUri() in E:\LocalAgent5\work\eba82aa7dfd1d8ff\src\SCA.Modules.Core\Resolver\PublicationResolver.cs:line 58
   at SCA.Modules.Core.Providers.Content.DefaultContentProvider.GetPage(String url) in E:\LocalAgent5\work\eba82aa7dfd1d8ff\src\SCA.Modules.Core\Providers\Content\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 98
   at SCA.Modules.Core.Providers.Content.DefaultContentProvider.BuildViewModel(String url) in E:\LocalAgent5\work\eba82aa7dfd1d8ff\src\SCA.Modules.Core\Providers\Content\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 177
   at SCA.Modules.Core.Providers.Content.DefaultContentByUrlProvider.Retrieve(String urlOrTcmUri) in E:\LocalAgent5\work\eba82aa7dfd1d8ff\src\SCA.Modules.Core\Providers\Content\DefaultContentByUrlProvider.cs:line 51
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at SCA.Modules.Core.Binders.TypedModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) in E:\LocalAgent5\work\eba82aa7dfd1d8ff\src\SCA.Modules.Core\Binders\TypedModelBinder.cs:line 82
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
```

[image]