# The DynamicMappingsRetriever class from SDL assembly is not thread safe

Tags: web8, dd4t, discovery, publicationresolver

I did some investigation on my previous question:
[No matching Localization found for Url](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17672/no-matching-localization-found-for-url)

Below is Stack Trace:

> 2017-11-23 15:50:41.3358|ERROR|Global.Exception.Handling|System.Exception: No matching Localization found for URL 'http://SomeUrl/' ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) at Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.DynamicMappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(String url) at Application.Resolvers.PublicationResolver.Resolve(Uri uri) in E:\LocalAgent4\work\eba82aa7dfd1d8ff\src\Application\Resolver\PublicationResolver.cs:line 109

The exception occurs internally in a SDL library on the `GetPublicationMapping` method of `Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.DynamicMappingRetriever` class on the following line, but those values are not null:

```
this._mappings[url] = publicationMapping;
```

*Note: We are using DD4T 2.1.4 for DD4T.model, So 2.1 for DD4T and Web 8 for Tridion.*

8.1.0.1239 for `Tridion.ContentDelivery`

I found an article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320621/throw-a-nullreferenceexception-while-calling-the-set-item-method-of-a-dictionary
That explains that NullReferenceException could be triggered when several threads try access the same dictionary object simultaneously, and this is most probably what is happening in our case, since we only see this error sporadically and cannot reproduce it on lower environments, since those does not have too many requests coming in at the same time.

The `DynamicMappingsRetriever` class from SDL assembly is not thread safe, but our code is using it as if it was thread safe. That is why sometimes we get this error.

On our code we are using below:

```
try
{
    // NOTE: we're not using UrlToLocalizationMapping here, because we may match too eagerly on a base URL when there is a matching mapping with a more specific URL.
    var mapping = _mappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(url);
    if (mapping == null || (!mapping.Port.IsNullOrEmpty() && mapping.Port != uri.Port.ToString()))
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("No matching Localization found for URL '{0}'", url));
    }
    return mapping;
}
```

So `_mappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(url);` is returning null.

Is there any hotfix SDL provided for this issue?

A solution is to make our code thread safe like below, but I am not sure how it would impact the sites on production.

```
lock (_publicationResolverLocker)
{
    var mapping = _mappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(url);
    if (mapping == null || (!mapping.Port.IsNullOrEmpty() && mapping.Port != uri.Port.ToString()))
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("No matching Localization found for URL '{0}'", url));
    }
    return mapping;
}
```

Comment: Can you **edit** your question and clarify some details, you are mentioning an SDL assembly, but SDL is a pretty large company, and you should at least mention the product you are talking about (I think you might be talking about DXA, but please clarify those details, like product name and version etc.), because without that, like you previous question, you might not get any answer.

Comment: It would be good to raise this issue with Customer Support so they can get this hotfixed. In the mean time I recommend to maintain a threadsafe map to do the thread safety yourself.

Comment: @BartKoopman I edited my question, we are using DD4T only.

Comment: @NeeleshRaghuvanshi I would cache the mapping in a concurrent dictionary or similar to prevent the lookup being done every time. That way your locking code will not have much impact. In the mean time I'd like to ask you to raise an issue in the dd4t .Net project on Github.

Comment: I checked the code and it is not a DD4T issue at all. The stack trace contains a custom implementation of the IPublicationResolver (which is part of DD4T). The custom code calls the DynamicMappingsRetriever which is part of the CIL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved from version https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sdl.Web.Delivery/8.5.1041 onwards.